# Patterns for proxying and implementation hiding in Rust?

Tags: rust

So I'm an experienced developer, pretty new to Rust, expert in Java - but started out in assembly language, so I get memory and allocation, and have written enough compiler-y things to fathom the borrow-checker pretty well.

I decided to port a very useful, high-performance bitset-based graph library I wrote in Java, both to use it in a larger eventual project, and because it's darned useful.  Since it's all integer positions in bitsets, and if you want an object graph you map indices into an array or whatever - I'm not tangled up in building a giant tree of objects that reference each other, which would be a mess to try to do in Rust.  The problem I'm trying to solve is much simpler - so simple I feel like I must be missing an obvious pattern for how to do it:

Looking over the various bit-set libraries available for Rust, [FixedBitSet](https://docs.rs/fixedbitset/0.4.0/fixedbitset/struct.FixedBitSet.html) seemed like a good fit.  **However**, I would rather not expose it via my API and tie every consumer of my library irrevocably to FixedBitSet (it is nice, but, it can also be useful to swap in, say, an implementation backed by atomics; and being married to `usize` may not be ideal, but FixedBitSet is).

In Java, you'd just create an interface that wraps an instance of the concrete type, and exposes the functionality you want, hiding the implementation type.  In Rust, you have traits, so it's easy enough to implement:

```
pub trait Bits<'i, S: Sized + Add<S>> {
    fn size(&'i self) -> S;
    fn contains(&'i self, s: S) -> bool;
...
impl<'i, 'a> Bits<'i, usize> for FixedBitSet {
    fn size(&'i self) -> usize {
        self.len()
    }
    fn contains(&'i self, s: usize) -> bool {
        FixedBitSet::contains(self, s)
    }
...
```

this gets a little ugly in that, if I don't want to expose `FixedBitSet`, everything has to return `Box<dyn Bits<'a, usize> + 'a>`, but so be it for now - though that creates its own problems with the compiler not knowing the size of `dyn Bits...`.

So far so good.  Where it gets *interesting* (did I say this was a weirdly simple problem?) is *proxying an iterator*.  Rust iterators seem to be irrevocably tied to a concrete Trait type which has an *associated type*.  So you **can't** really abstract it (well, sort of, via `Box<dyn Iterator<Item=usize> + 'a> where ...`, and it looks like it might be possible to create a trait that extends iterator and also has a `type Item` on it, and implement it for `u32`, `u64`, `usize` and ?? maybe the compiler coalesces the `type Item` members of the traits?).  And as far as I can tell, you can't narrow the return type in a trait implementation method to something other than the trait specifies, either.

This gets further complicated by the fact that the [Ones](https://docs.rs/fixedbitset/0.4.0/fixedbitset/struct.Ones.html) type in FixedBitSet for iterating set bits *has its own lifetime* - but Rust's Iterator does not - so any generic Iterator implementation is going to need to return an iterator scoped to that lifetime, not `'_` or there will be issues with how long the iterator lives vis-a-vis the thing that created it.

The tidiest thing I could come up with - which is not tidy at all - after experimenting with various containers for an iterator (an implementation of Bits that adds an offset to the base value is also useful) that expose it, was something like:

```
pub trait Biterable<'a, 'b, S: Sized + Add<S>, I: Iterator<Item = S> + 'b>  where 'a: 'b {
    fn set_bits<'c>(&'a mut self) -> I where I: 'c, 'b: 'c;
}
```

which is implementable enough:

```
impl<'a, 'b> Biterable<'a, 'b, usize, Ones<'b>> for FixedBitSet where 'a: 'b {
    fn set_bits<'c>(&'a mut self) -> Ones<'b> where Ones<'b>: 'c, 'b: 'c {
        self.ones()
    }
}
```

but then, we know we're going to be dealing with Boxes.  So, we're going to need an implementation for that.  Great!  A signature like `impl<'a, 'b> Biterable<'a, 'b, usize, Ones<'b>> for Box<FixedBitSet> where 'a: 'b {` is implementable.  **BUUUUUUT**, that's not what anything is going to return if we're not exposing `FixedBitSet` anywhere - we need it for `Box<dyn Bits<...> + ...>`.  For *that*, we wind up in a hall of mirrors, scribbling out increasingly baroque and horrifying (and uncompilable) variants on

```
impl<'a, 'b, B> Biterable<'a, 'b, usize, &'b mut dyn Iterator<Item=usize>>
   for Box<dyn B + 'a> where 'a: 'b, B : Bits<'a, usize> + Biterable<'a, 'b, usize, Ones<'b>> {
```

in a vain search for something that compiles and works (this fails because while `Bits` and `Biterable` are traits, evidently `Biterable + Bits` is not a trait).  Seriously - a stateless, no-allocation-needed wrapper for one call on this thing returning one call on that thing, just not exposing that thing's type to the caller.  That's it.  The Java equivalent would be `Supplier<T> a = ...; return () -> a.get();`

I have to be thinking about this problem wrong.  How?

Comment: I wouldn't say you've been thinking about it wrong, just that Rust does not have the required features yet to support your use case. You probably need [type_alias_impl_trait](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63063) and [generic_associated_types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265).

Comment: I think parameterizing `Bits` with `S` doesn't actually make it more generic. If your public API exposes a `dyn Bits<usize>`, changing it to e.g. `Bits<u64>` (to support a change to a different backend?) is backwards-incompatible anyway, so there is no apparent advantage to having `S` as a parameter vs. having it as an associated type (e.g. `dyn Bits<Index = usize>`) or even just hard-coding it to `usize` as in kmdreko's answer.

Comment: I've actually looked at both `Bits<Index=usize>` and `Bits<S>` - the point is not to tie the trait eternally to a particular size of integer.  You're likely right that the generic may add nothing in this case - I have not really developed instincts as to which - generics or associated types - is right for a given situation.

Comment: BTW, to clarify my comment on Ones having a lifetime:  If you have a trait that specifies an iterator type - `trait Foo< I : dyn Iterator<Item=Blah>>`, with `fn whatev(&self) : I` but the concrete iterator type specifies a lifetime on its type, it seems there is no way to handle it cleanly other than the otherwise useless `'b` lifetime in `Biterable`, to give the returned concrete iterator some lifetime other than `'static`.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. If you have a `Graph` type and it has some API method that exposes a `dyn Bits<usize>` or `dyn Bits<Index = usize>`, regardless of which you pick, you've **already** anchored `Graph` to `usize`. Changing the implementation of `Graph` from `FixedBitSet` to `FancyBitSet` will either be a breaking change, or you'll have to wrap `FancyBitSet` in something that *also* implements `Bits<usize>`, which means that `Bits` is failing at its goal of isolating the external API of `Graph` from its internal implementation.

Comment: If the external API of `Graph` *doesn't* expose `Bits<usize>` in any way (`Bits` is a completely internal trait), then I don't see why you'd ever need a `dyn Bits<anything>`. I think kmdreko is correct: you're vastly over-complicating things. Without a fuller picture of the requirements and constraints you're trying to satisfy, it's not really possible to say exactly how, but you seem to have a lot of type and lifetime parameters that just aren't doing anything, at least in this code.

Comment: Well, yeah, if you want to switch types _as a client_ that's a breaking change; the point is more to be able to choose the right implementation initially (for example, there are many graphs on the planet that have < 65536 nodes and would fit just fine in a `u16` graph).  Similarly, an [atomic bit set](https://github.com/timboudreau/util/blob/master/bits/src/main/java/com/mastfrog/bits/AtomicBitsImpl.java#L457) is a very useful tool for lock-free concurrent processing of a queue, and a single straightforward interface to that is a good thing.

Comment: I thought the client wasn't supposed to know about `usize` or `FixedBitSet`? Perhaps it would be easier to understand if you flesh out the design a bit more.

Comment: The point is, if I know I'm dealing in small graphs, I might want a Graph<u16> that produces Bits<u16>;  and it should be minimally invasive to alter such code to use a different type as possible.

Answer (score 3):

It does certainly seem like you're over-complicating things. You have a lot of lifetime annotations that don't seem necessary. [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=478caee526ab9bf4da6c7854197686c7)'s a straightforward implementation (ignoring generic `S`):

```
use fixedbitset::FixedBitSet; // 0.2.0

pub trait Bits {
    fn size(&self) -> usize;
    fn contains(&self, s: usize) -> bool;
    fn set_bits<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize> + 'a>;
}

impl Bits for FixedBitSet {
    fn size(&self) -> usize {
        self.len()
    }
    fn contains(&self, s: usize) -> bool {
        self.contains(s)
    }
    fn set_bits<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize> + 'a> {
        Box::new(self.ones())
    }
}

pub fn get_bits_from_api() -> impl Bits {
    FixedBitSet::with_capacity(64)
}
```

If you want the index type to be anonymous as well, make it an associated type and *not define it* when exposing your `Bits`:

```
use fixedbitset::FixedBitSet; // 0.2.0

pub trait Bits {
    type Idx: std::ops::Add<Self::Idx>;

    fn size(&self) -> Self::Idx;
    fn contains(&self, s: Self::Idx) -> bool;
    fn set_bits<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Self::Idx> + 'a>;
}

impl Bits for FixedBitSet {
    type Idx = usize;

    fn size(&self) -> Self::Idx {
        self.len()
    }
    fn contains(&self, s: Self::Idx) -> bool {
        self.contains(s)
    }
    fn set_bits<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Self::Idx> + 'a> {
        Box::new(self.ones())
    }
}

pub fn get_bits_from_api() -> impl Bits {
                           // ^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have <Idx = usize>
    FixedBitSet::with_capacity(64)
}

fn main() {
    let bits = get_bits_from_api();

    // just a demonstration that it compiles
    let size = bits.size();
    if bits.contains(size) {
        for indexes in bits.set_bits() {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

I highly encourage against this though for many reasons. 1) You'd need many more constraints than just `Add` for this to be remotely usable. 2) You are severely limited with `impl Bits`; its not fully defined so you can't have `dyn Bits` or store it in a struct. 3) I don't see much benefit in being generic in this regard.

Comment: The point was _not_ to tie `Bits` to `usize` or any other specific integer type.  Implementing `Bits` itself is easy enough - until you get to wrappering an iterator produced by `FixedBitSet` without exposing the implementation type of the underlying iterator.